# How to stream and collect multiple max items based on a specific fields

Tags: java, collections, stream, java-stream

```
 List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setMake("Honda");
    car.setYear(1998);
    car.setColor("red");
    carList.add(car);

    car = new Car();
    car.setMake("Honda");
    car.setYear(2020);
    car.setColor("red");
    carList.add(car);

    car = new Car();
    car.setMake("Audi");
    car.setYear(2022);
    car.setColor("red");
    carList.add(car);

    car = new Car();
    car.setMake("Toyota");
    car.setYear(2021);
    car.setColor("blue");
    carList.add(car);

    car = new Car();
    car.setMake("Toyota");
    car.setYear(2007);
    car.setColor("blue");
    carList.add(car);
```

How to stream and collect to a map with color as key and value has list of cars with oldest car by make?
the final Map should have

```
{
  "red": [
    {
      "make": "Honda",
      "year": "1998"
    },
    {
      "make": "Audi",
      "year": "2022"
    }
  ],
  "blue": [
    {
      "make": "Toyota",
      "year": "2007"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once the groupingBy is used to group based on color, having issue to reduce the list (values) to oldest car by make and then collect to a map as whole.

was able to get the expected result by

```
Map<String, Map<String, Optional<Car>>> carMap =
                carList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getColor,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getMake,
                                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Car::getYear)))));
```

{red={Audi=Optional[Car(make=Audi, year=2022, color=red)], Honda=Optional[Car(make=Honda, year=1998, color=red)]}, blue={Toyota=Optional[Car(make=Toyota, year=2007, color=blue)]}}

But unable to flatmap the values in the nested map to a list of Cars in the parent map.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal runnable example which illustrates your problem. You say "Once the groupingBy is used to group based on color, having issue to reduce the list" but you havent shown the code you are asking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group a set of objects into sorted lists using java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171283/how-to-group-a-set-of-objects-into-sorted-lists-using-java-8) or also [Java 8, Lambda: Sorting within grouped Lists and merging all groups to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679265/java-8-lambda-sorting-within-grouped-lists-and-merging-all-groups-to-a-list)

Comment: @tgdavies updated the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should just have to map the collected values:

```
cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::color,
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Car::make,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Car::year)), Optional::get)
        ), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()))));
```

But really, this is where streams get unreadable...

**Update**

To write this in at least a little more readable fashion:

```
Collector<Car, ?, Car> eldest = Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Car::year)),
        Optional::get);

Collector<Car, ?, List<Car>> eldestByMake = Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Car::make, eldest), 
        map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()));

cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::color, eldestByMake));
```

Comment: I just tried running this.  It doesn't produce the intended result.  It produces a structure that has `Car` objects at the leaves rather than maps.  That is, `Map<String, Collection<Car>>` rather than `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`

Comment: I've updated my answer to return a `Map<String, List<Car>>`.

Comment: @CryptoFool, there was no requirement to return a `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`.

Comment: I was reading the desired result in the question as being fairly literal...that `[` and `]` represent a List, and `{` and `}` represent a Map.  But perhaps the OP didn't intend that it be taken so literally.  The text of the question certainly doesn't confirm this interpretation. And I see now that the OP accepted your answer, so that seals it.  So I flipped my vote!

Comment: Thanks, I could have been wrong, too, but the last sentence of the OPs question made me think he wants a list of Cars :-)